# bash How to print all values from a key value pair.

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a key value pairs separated by a comma (,). I want to print all the values with a comma as a separator. Just to load them into a mysql database.

raw data format:

key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value31 value32, key4:value4, keyn:valuen
key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3 value3, key4:value41 value42, keyn:valuen

required format:

value1, value2, value31 value32, value4, valuen
value1, value2, value3, value41 value42, valuen

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
sed -e 's/[^,: ]*://g' yourfile.txt
```

output:

```
value1, value2, value31 value32, value4, valuen value1, value2, value3 value3, value41 value42, valuen
```

Comment: You don't need a pipe here, just `sed -e 's/[^,: ]*://g' yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Simple **awk** solution:

```
awk '{ gsub(/[^[:space:],]+:/,"") }1' file
```

- `gsub(/[^[:space:],]+:/,"")` - remove all *keys* along with initial key/value separator `:`

The output:

```
value1, value2, value31 value32, value4, valuen
value1, value2, value3 value3, value41 value42, valuen
```